# DenseNet: Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to build up a Densenet but stuck with the following error.. 
Here is the smallest example to reproduce:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import tensorflow.keras.layers as tfkl

def create_model(input_dim):

    feature_list = list()
    input_x = tfkl.Input(shape=input_dim, name="Inputs")
    feature_list.append(input_x)
    x = tfkl.Conv2D(16, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding="same", name="Conv1")(input_x)
    feature_list.append(x)

    x = tfkl.Concatenate(axis=-1, name="Concat1")(feature_list)
    x = tfkl.Conv2D(16, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding="same", name="Conv2")(x)
    feature_list.append(x)
    x = tfkl.Concatenate(axis=-1, name="Concat2")(feature_list)

    return tf.keras.Model(inputs=input_x, outputs=x)

z = create_model((128,128,2))
```

The error I get:

```
ValueError: Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor Tensor("Conv2/Identity:0", shape=(None, 128, 128, 16), dtype=float32) at layer "Concat1". The following previous layers were accessed without issue: ['Inputs', 'Conv1']
```

I could not realize what is wrong with this model?

The idea behind using `feature_list` here is that later I can create a dense block with a variable number of convolution layers, i.e.:

```
    for i in range(nb_layers):
          nb_filter += growth_rate
          x = tfkl.Concatenate(axis=-1)(feature_list)
          x = tfkl.Conv2D(nb_filter , kernel_size=(3, 3), padding="same")(x)
          feature_list.append(x)
```

Furthermore, if I comment out the following two lines in create_model function:

```
    #feature_list.append(x)
    #x = tfkl.Concatenate(axis=-1, name="Concat2")(feature_list)
```

then the model works without problems (so it means that generally Concatenate works correctly):

```
z.summary()
Model: "model"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
Inputs (InputLayer)             [(None, 128, 128, 2) 0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Conv1 (Conv2D)                  (None, 128, 128, 16) 304         Inputs[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Concat1 (Concatenate)           (None, 128, 128, 18) 0           Inputs[0][0]                     
                                                                 Conv1[0][0]                      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Conv2 (Conv2D)                  (None, 128, 128, 16) 2608        Concat1[0][0]                    
==================================================================================================
Total params: 2,912
Trainable params: 2,912
Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

Comment: why using `feature_list`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think that keras functional model creation does not run eagerly and the lists are just references. So when you append the Conv2 output to feature list it is also reflected at the following line: `x = tfkl.Concatenate(axis=-1, name="Concat1")(feature_list)` where you don't really have Conv2 output.

What you should do is to call the Concat layer with a copy of the features list. See the example below:

```
import copy
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import tensorflow.keras.layers as tfkl

def create_model(input_dim):

    feature_list = list()
    input_x = tfkl.Input(shape=input_dim, name="Inputs")
    feature_list.append(input_x)
    x = tfkl.Conv2D(16, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding="same", name="Conv1")(input_x)
    feature_list.append(x)

    x = tfkl.Concatenate(axis=-1, name="Concat1")(copy.copy(feature_list))
    x = tfkl.Conv2D(16, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding="same", name="Conv2")(x)
    feature_list.append(x)
    print(feature_list)
    x = tfkl.Concatenate(axis=-1, name="Concat2")(copy.copy(feature_list))

    return tf.keras.Model(inputs=input_x, outputs=x)

z = create_model((128,128,2))
```

Comment: thanks, I got the point.. So the tfkl methods are not really executed but just create a call graph while 'feature_list' requires an eager execution to be evaluated

Answer (score 0):

I think that's because of the names of your layers, your trying to concatenate an array with layer names that are the same : [input_x, x, x], try this :

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import tensorflow.keras.layers as tfkl

def create_model(input_dim):

    feature_list = list()
    input_x = tfkl.Input(shape=input_dim)
    feature_list.append(input_x)
    conv1 = tfkl.Conv2D(16, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding="same")(input_x)
    feature_list.append(conv1)

    concat1 = tfkl.Concatenate(axis=-1)(feature_list)
    conv2 = tfkl.Conv2D(16, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding="same")(concat1)
    feature_list.append(conv2)

    concat2 = tfkl.Concatenate(axis=-1)(feature_list)

    return tf.keras.Model(inputs=input_x, outputs=concat2)

z = create_model((128,128,2))
```